# How do I get the difference between 2 dates? jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to calculate the total days between selected #from day and #to day, using jquery datepicker

"I have read a lot of asked questions before writing this so I am just asking why the following code doesn't work.."

this is the code:

```
$(function() {

$( "#from" ).datepicker({
numberOfMonths: 1,
minDate:0,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
$("input[name='to']").val(selectedDate);
var dayFrom = selectedDate; /* Selected From Date */
}
});

$( "#to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
numberOfMonths: 1,
minDate:0,
dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
var dayTo = selectedDate; /* Selected To Date */

$(dayFrom, dayTo).change(function(){
if($(dayFrom).val() && $(dayTo).val()){
var startDate = parseDate($(dayFrom).val());
var endDate = parseDate($(dayTo).val());
var days = calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate);
var price = calcPrice(days);

$('#finalDagen').html(days);
}
});
function parseDate(s){
var parts = s.split('/');
return new Date(parts[2], parts[0]-1, parts[1]);
}
function calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate){
return (endDate-startDate)/(1000*60*60*24);
}
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observations

- The change handler should be registered to the from and to elements, not to the variables holding the values
- use the widget method getDate() to fetch the date value of the widget
- The change event should be registered in the dom ready handler - not inside the `onClose` method

It should be

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $from = $("#from"),
        $to = $("#to");

    $from.datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $to.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $from.add($to).change(function () {
        var dayFrom = $from.datepicker('getDate');
        var dayTo = $to.datepicker('getDate');
        if (dayFrom && dayTo) {
            var days = calcDaysBetween(dayFrom, dayTo);

            $('#finalDagen').html(days);
        }
    });

    function calcDaysBetween(startDate, endDate) {
        return (endDate - startDate) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9EZXx/)

Comment: I just realize that gives also odd numbers..exp if you choose march 30 to march 31 I get:0.9583333333333334 How can I solve that..

Answer (score -1):

Try subtracting the two:

```
var dayDifference = dayTo - dayFrom;
```